# How to convert LibreOffice Impress to video with custom animations?

Tags: video, presentation

I am wondering whether it is possible to convert a LibreOffice Impress presentation into a video (to upload on YouTube), while preserving custom animations on slides.

There is a possibility to export the presentation to a .swf Macromedia Flash file, but the custom animations are not preserved.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a screen recording / capture tool. With this solution you can even define your individual timing from slide to slide.

Which software to use? Depending on your operating system there are many free or low cost solutions available. There are even web-based services.

This [blog post](http://www.technonutty.com/2015/07/best-top-10-screen-recording-softwares-online-utilities.html) lists 10 of them. I copied that list here for reference.

Desktop Software:

- [IceCream](http://filehippo.com/download_icecream_screen_recorder/) (Windows)
- [ActivePresenter](http://atomisystems.com/activepresenter/) (Windows)
- [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) (Windows)
- [Snagit](https://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) (Windows/Mac)
- [Jing](https://www.techsmith.com/jing.html) (Windows/Mac)

Web Services:

- [Webinaria](http://www.webinaria.com/)
- [Apowersoft](http://www.apowersoft.com/)
- [Screenr](https://www.screenr.com/)
- [ScreenToaster](http://www.icyte.com/system/snapshots/fs1/6/1/3/6/6136fdcd5ad0da964634b9747f65ac5f2df32d5c/index.html)
- [ScreenCastle](http://screencastle.com/)

I'm sure next year there will be different options. That's why this list can only be an overview and starting point for your own research.

You might need another tool to finally crop your recorded video to 1280x720 or 1920x1080 pixel, because the screen recorder might have recorded an odd rectangle that you have drawn with the mouse. My favorite is [VirtualDub](http://virtualdub.org) for Windows.

Comment: list of GNU-Linux screen recorders, included as a comment because I have not tested all of them but they are in the Debian Bookworm repos, there are some others [not included here] just for command-line recording. : byzanz, deepin-screen-recorder, gnome-shell-extension-easyscreencast, kazam, peek, recordmydesktop, simplescreenrecorder, vimix, vokoscreen, wf-recorder